# Spring Data Rest with Cache

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I was learning **Spring Data Rest** but I didn't find how to use **Cache** in Spring Data Rest.
How can i use **Cache** with **Spring Data Rest's curd/page** .
Or should I use **JPA+Cache** and ignore **Spring Data Rest**?

If I misunderstanding anything please remind me.

best regard

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach:

1) Override your repos methods `findById` and `findAll`, make them `Cacheable`:

```java
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Cacheable("myEntities")
    @Override
    Optional<MyEntity> findById(Long id);

    @Cacheable("pagedMyEntities")
    @Override
    Page<MyEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);  
}
```

2) Create a [RepositoryEventHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler) to evict your caches:

```java
@RepositoryEventHandler 
public class MyEntityEventHandler {

  private final CacheManager cacheManager;

  public MyEntityEventHandler(CacheManager cacheManager) {
     this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
  }

  @HandleAfterCreate
  @HandleAfterSave
  @HandleAfterDelete
  public void handleCachesEviction(MyEntity entity) {
      Optional.ofNullable(cacheManager.getCache("myEntities"))
          .ifPresent(c -> c.evict(entity.getId()));

      Optional.ofNullable(cacheManager.getCache("pagedMyEntities"))
          .ifPresent(c -> c.clear());
  }
}
```

3) And of course create a cache manager bean, for example:

```java
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
    }
}
```